# trying to convert this file to python 3 and getting the error module not found

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using the solitaire.py file and trying to convert it to Python 3. It was originally 2.7 and works fine in that version but need it in 3 so I can make an AI with `PyTorch` to play it but I'm having an issue where:

```py
from Canvas import Rectangle, CanvasText, Group, Window
```

shows the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Canvas'
```

Does anyone have any idea as to why or if there is something similar I could use in python 3 to make it work?

Comment: Have you installed it for Python 3?

Comment: im not sure what to install tbh i never had to install anything to get it working on python 2.7

Comment: If it's a Kivy Canvas, you'll need to install the Python 3 version of Kivy.

Comment: Somebody/something _must_ have installed it, because it's not a standard Python module/library. You can get Kivy from [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/Kivy/). It might have been part of some large framework you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

`Canvas` was [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/2.6.html?highlight=canvas#deprecations-and-removals) in Python 3.

Instead you can use `tkinter` by doing: [[docs](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html)]

```py
from tkinter import Canvas
```

Or do this:

```py
from tkinter import *
```

Comment: thank you is there anyway to work around the imports from it (e.g group, rectangle)? As the file uses those?

Comment: Yes, I updated but just `from tkinter import *` and it should work similar to how it did before and other tkinter modules will be available.

Comment: thank you i was mostly asking cause the class straight after it is class Group(Group):
   def bind(self, sequence=None, command=None):
        return self.canvas.tag_bind(self.id, sequence, command) which used the Group import

Comment: I don't see the `Group` class as part of `tkinter` so it may not work as expected.