# Getting "ModuleNotFoundError" trying to import Tkinter Canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas

I'm trying to do the same thing Marc Leese tried to do here but didn't seem to get a clear answer on (at least none that works for me): [trying to convert this file to python 3 and getting the error module not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58511730/trying-to-convert-this-file-to-python-3-and-getting-the-error-module-not-found#)

That is, use in a Python 3+ environment the solitaire.py example code as found e.g. here: https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/python/+/0d4194853e08d3244931523470331c00dfb94863/Python-2.7.3/Demo/tkinter/guido/solitaire.py

Specifically, I'm running Python 3.7.9 through Spyder 3.3.6.

When I try to run the above code, I first get an error that Tkinter is not found. When I correct Tkinter to tkinter, however, I still get an error that says:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Canvas'`

Regardless of whether I use `from tkinter import *` or `from tkinter import Canvas` I keep getting the same error.

The whole code block in question is:

```
# Imports
import math
import random
from tkinter import *
from Canvas import Rectangle, CanvasText, Group, Window
# Fix a bug in Canvas.Group as distributed in Python 1.4.  The
# distributed bind() method is broken.  Rather than asking you to fix
# the source, we fix it here by deriving a subclass:
class Group(Group):
    def bind(self, sequence=None, command=None):
        return self.canvas.tag_bind(self.id, sequence, command)
```

I've noticed before that example code using `import *` did not seem to work as in the example, but before I've always managed to find a workaround.

If someone could explain what's going from here/how to fix it I'd be very much obliged!

Comment: there is no module Canvas, a module, not a class, you usually import from modules, where in your code do you see a module that you import from that is named Canvas? also: I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with tkinter. `Canvas` is not a module provided by tkinter, and neither is `Rectangle`, `CanvasText`, `Group`, or `Window`. Can you show a link to documentation about the module you're trying to import?

Comment: Hey Mattiis. As I wrote in my post, this isn't my code, I'm trying to get working one of the demo example programs included in the python package. You can see the entire program in my second link, as well as elsewhere if you google "tkinter guido solitaire".

Comment: @BryanOakley `from tkinter import Canvas` works fine for me in 3.9, and `from Tkinter import Canvas` works in 2.7.

Comment: Hey Bryan, thanks for the answer.

One of the answers in the first question I linked suggested importing Canvas from tkinter. I took my cue from there.

But perhaps they were mistaken, and I'm confused and should be trying to install a Canvas module which is unrelated to tkinter?

Comment: @MattDMo because you are importing a class from **`tkinter` module**, the OP's code contains `Canvas` module: `from Canvas import ...`, unless you have a package named `Canvas` or a file named `Canvas.py`, you don't have that module, you can obviously try it yourself, simply go and run `import Canvas` in python and see if it works (it may work if you have what I mentioned, but.. otherwise you will get an error)

Comment: @nadafanboy I searched the phrase, a lot of results were referencing `Python2`, so it would be pretty logical if it didn't work for you if you are using `Python3`, it may be that this sample is not included in `Python3` packaged and stuff, so you either install `Python2` (not suggested) or find another sample code that is compatible with `Python3` out-of-the-box (recommended)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've copied some very old code that apparently depends on a module named "Canvas" (for example, a file named Canvas.py). This module is not part of tkinter. You will need to find the original `Canvas.py` file

Comment: Thanks! I haven't found the original module, but I think your answer at least explains the problem for me and the other question from over a year ago.

For anyone else with the same issue: I personally ended up following @Matiis advice and found a more recent tkinter solitaire example program by Andereoo to use instead.